Error: Could not resolve host API HOSTINGER
El siguiente codigo esta hecho en PHP, llevo días revisandolo hasta que hoy lo monte en mi localhost que esta en xampp y apache y funciono perfectamente, me devuelve las cadenas del API, pero al meterlo a mi página que esta montada en HOSTINGER me sale el error que no resuelve el host.
Con un poco más de contexto, no son las credenciales reales y utilizando la misma estructura que aqui coloco en un inicio se programo en una macro en excel el cual funciona perfectamente, a pesar del _ que tiene el host. Esta API es de proveedor y se requiere consumir:
<?php
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);

        // Inicializar cURL
        $ch = curl_init();

        // URL del API y datos de autenticación
        $url = "https://scisa_identity.actinver.com.mx/connect/token";
        $grant_type = "client_credentials";
        $scope = "openid email roles profile ApiSigloFX_scope offline_access";
        $client_id = "Fondeadora";
        $client_secret = "63f0a0e8-d2d0-12ce-b361-c651569181e0";

        // Datos para la solicitud POST
        $data = [
            'grant_type' => $grant_type,
            'scope' => $scope,
            'client_id' => $client_id,
            'client_secret' => $client_secret
        ];

        // Mostrar los datos que se están enviando
        echo "Datos enviados: ";
        print_r($data);
        echo "<br>";

        // Establecer la URL y otras opciones necesarias
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4); // Forzar uso de IPv4

        // // Configurar servidores DNS específicos (si está disponible)
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_DNS_SERVERS, '8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4'); // Servidores DNS de Google

        // // Configurar el tiempo de espera
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30); // Tiempo máximo para establecer conexión
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); // Tiempo máximo para ejecutar la solicitud

        // // Obtener más información de depuración
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true); // Mostrar información de depuración
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true); // Incluir encabezados en la salida

        //EVITAR EL CERTIFICADO SSL
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

        // Ejecutar la solicitud
        $response = curl_exec($ch);

        // Verificar si hubo errores en la solicitud
        if (curl_errno($ch)) {
            echo 'Error: ' . curl_error($ch);
        } else {
            // Mostrar la respuesta completa para depuración
            echo "Respuesta de la API: " . htmlspecialchars($response) . "<br>";
    
            // Separar los encabezados y el cuerpo de la respuesta
            $header_size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
            $header = substr($response, 0, $header_size);
            $body = substr($response, $header_size);
    
            echo "Encabezados de la respuesta: " . htmlspecialchars($header) . "<br>";
            echo "Cuerpo de la respuesta: " . htmlspecialchars($body) . "<br>";
    
            // Decodificar la respuesta JSON
            $json = json_decode($body, true);
    
            // Verificar si el token está presente
            if (isset($json['access_token'])) {
                $token = $json['access_token'];
                echo "Access Token: " . $token;
            } else {
                echo "Error obteniendo el access_token. Respuesta completa decodificada: ";
                print_r($json); // Mostrar la respuesta completa para entender la estructura
            }
        }
        
            // Cerrar la conexión
            curl_close($ch);
?>

Me voltie al soporte técnico de Hostinger y me indican que mi DNS, mis servicios están bien.
Incluso pudiese tener líenas que estan demás, pero lo hice por tanta prueba y con la intención de resolvero, hasta que se me ocurrio probarlo en el localhost.
Alguno de ustedes les pasa lo mismo? Gracias


si esas son tus verdaderas credenciales, borra esta pregunta y cambia tus credenciales ya que cualquiera las puede usar para mal. 2) Por otro lado no se entiende el error, siempre que tengas el mensaje de error pegalo en tu pregunta, ya que no se entiende cual host  no resuleve: tu domino? el dominio del api?.  Estas usando un vps ? un cpanel? ...


Adicionalmente el dominio scisa_identity.actinver.com.mx esta mal formado ya que un el guion bajo no esta permitido, debes cambiarlo por un guion normal "-" e ir a tu proveedor de dominio y crear un nuevo registro scisa-identity.actinver.com.mx para que apunte a la ip de tu servidor.

Gracias, hablando del guión bajo ( _ ) si esta bien porque como lo comente en la pregunta editada, se hizo prueba en una macro en excel, adicional ayer probe el codigo en mi localhost y funciona perfectamente. Pero en mi página productiva que esta hospedadad en hostinger el error que devuelve es: Error: Could not resolve host: scisa_identity.actinver.com.mx. El codigo es compatible con PHP 8 y anteriores y help desk de Hostinger se limita a indicarme que todos mis parametros estan correctos. Soy Admin del cpanel y ya no se que más moverle.


tu dns no esta registrado, eso es facil de saber, vas a alguna pagina de dns propagation y pones tu subdominio como aca https://www.whatsmydns.net/#CNAME/scisa_identity.actinver.com.mx ahi te das cuenta que no lo haz configurado en tu proveedor de dominio. En palabras mas simples: tienes que crear un registro CNAME para tu subdominio scisa-identity (con el guion bajo porque en INTERNET no estan permitidos los guiones bajos).


Te dejo de ejemplo un registro  de un subdominio de  tu dominio que si esta configurado https://www.whatsmydns.net/#CNAME/api.actinver.com.mx

Gracias @clay le mando la información al proveedor pero me salta una pregunta y solo por el echo de aprender: por qué con el aplicativo postman ingreso los mismos datos y funciona perfectamente? incluso lo probé también con Swagger y de la misma manera funciona perfectamente?

Asi nada mas es dificil de saber porque depende de tu entorno... lo que tienes que saber es que si en LOCAL ese subdominio resuleve la ip del servidor y en internet no, es porque hay una configuracion en al gun punto de tu red LOCAL donde ese subdominio esta configurado. Lo mas comun es que estes usando algun programa como xampp y hayas creado un dominio virtual para que apunte a la ip del servidor sin darte cuenta...

El proveedor comenta que la API esta configurada con certificados de seguridad por lo que no es un API publica y solo se podrá consumir dentro de la institución. Cambia mi estrategía pero la meta es la misma.
